# How to make a database table specifically for testing and create entitymanager based off that Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, jpa, testing

So for examples I may have a real table, User

```java
@Table('user')
@Entity
public class User(){
 @PrimaryId
 long id;
 String name;
 String email;
... etc. etc.
}
```

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends CrudRepository{
 whatever repository methods
}
```

```java
public class userRepositoryImpl{
 @PersistenceContext
 EntityManager em;

 public List<User> getUsersBasedOnCriteria(args){
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<User> cr = cb.createQuery(User.class);
  Root<User> root = criteriaBuilder.getRoot();
  
  ... stuff based on criteria builder

  
  return res;
 }
}
```

then I'd want something like TestUser that would be

```java
@Table('testUser')

public class TestUser{
.......
.......
.......
.......
}
```

but when I am running tests I want to setup a test user table that will be used.  The methods that I have seen to do that seem like they would mock the entire database, all the models, etc. but I just want this one test table that has certain aspects of the user table.  So I want an in memory db but I want it to only use the mocked info.  I also want to be able to test userRepositoryImpl on a 'fake' userRepository class

The reason I want to do this is because the current methods that I've seen be suggested did not work for my specific circumstance with how the database is set up and it makes more sense to me to use a fake table in this instance than fix whatever issue is preventing the current database from being set up in memory.  Excuse any errors in the snippets w/ how things are setup or annotations they are just examples I came up with for this question, not real code.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot's `DataJpaTest` you can specify which models you want to mock, by creating a "fake" schema with your custom table(s) and populating the table(s) with your custom data. Please check out the tutorial [here](https://zetcode.com/springboot/datajpatest/) on how to implement it .

Comment: I've tried this; however, it is trying to recreate the entire database when I put the @DataJpaTest annotation.  I am unsure of how to ask it just to make that one table

Comment: Yes, and it's a temporary DB that is dropped after the execution of the tests though...

Comment: the goal is that I would not create the rest of the db, only the one table.  There are other issues with how the DB I am working on is set up that make it not feasible to use datajpatest with the entire thing.

Comment: With this approach, you can choose to only have one table. The one that you want to use to test.

Comment: I've read through and attempted that solution before, and it appeared the @datajpatest recreates every table in the database.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't recreate your DB you are the one who mocks your DB on it, it is not anyway linked to your DB.  Did you see the [tutorial](https://zetcode.com/springboot/datajpatest/), the person is only mocking one table on his/her whole DB just like you want to: ``CREATE TABLE cities(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), population INT);``. The person might have millions of tables on his/her DB but they only chose this one table because it is the only table their are interested in testing, just like you.